# GoogleMaps with Fancybox

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, fancybox

I've been trying to show a GoogleMaps map, which is inside a fancybox div but, as it must be with display:none; from the beginning, once the map is loaded it's partially displayed:

```
    <div style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:-999;top:45px;left:300px;" id="divMapCreate" name="divMapCreate">
        <div id="createItemDiv2" style="border:1px solid;width:450px;">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create(array('action'=>'create2', 'type' => 'post', 'id'=>'createItem2', 'name'=>'createItem2')); ?>
            <table border="0" width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <strong>Creating an Item</strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="map_canvas_create" style="width: 450px; height: 350px"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->end('DONE - CREATE'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

How can I use Fancybox to show the map, but having its associated div with display:none; from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this issue a few times. The solution, in a nutshell, is not to pre-load the map but to load it after the container has become visible.

I think it's because GMap can't calculate the size it's container if it's hidden.